# Is there an option to insert a test case log in a particular order using rebot?

Tags: robotframework

I am using rebot merge option to merge two different test cases and produce the single test cases log and report. But then only concern is ordering. When I merged two different test cases using rebot then it successfully produced the single log file but the test cases were not in order. For example, if output1.xml has test cases 1,2,4 and output2.xml has test case 3,5. Now if I merge these two file using rebot merge option then I will get the merge output like 1,2,4,3,5 which is merging two different test cases but not in order. I am looking for merge output like 1,2,3,4,5.

Is there an option to insert a test case log in a particular order using rebot?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in [Merging output](http:///Users/laurent/Development/stash/pyforge/results/20160620-161920/output.xml) of Robot Framework. Test cases will be found in the order in which they are found in the file provided in input. So all you could get for your example if 1,2,4,3,5 or 3,5,1,2,4 (if you give output2.xml output1.xml as arguments)

Comment: Thanks for you answer!